# How to see why some pages have higher conversion rate then others?

Tags: conversion, conversion-rate, analytics

On wbesite that I work on, I get task to analyze why some pages have higher conversion rates then others (or why some pages have lower conversion rate).

For example Homepage have conversion rate 4% (for example), but Products page have 1%. Team want from me to see what cause this. There are few hypothesis, but they want from me to understand this better.

What things and steps should I do to get some insight about this? 
Is there some why that I get insight about this from Google Analytics, HotJar etc. or I need to conduct detailed user research (let's say they want to get insight about this only from analytics)?

Answer (score 1):

No analytics application is going to be able to tell you *why* users have done what they did (or didn't do). They just log stats and numbers, not emotions and motivations.

The only way to find out why people act in the way they do is to speak to them directly. So yes, detailed user research - possibly get users into a lab and run through scenarios with them and them observe and ask questions while they do, or set up some in-person interviews with users.

You could try a feedback tab on the app (HotJar and other analytics offer this) but there's no guarantee people will answer honestly, or even answer at all. And you're unlikely to get responses from people who have just bailed on the site - feedback options really only work for 'hot' leads; people who are already engaged with the site.

However, you don't necessarily *need* to find out why people have / haven't done something. You have your hypotheses as you state - so test those hypotheses out; change the site to address whatever you hypothesis is and observe the analytics to see if that change makes a difference.